# My RMI client is getting NoClassDefFoundErrors for Log4j when trying to run server methods

Tags: java, rmi

I have been searching all over the Internet, but I can't find a way to get the RMI code to behave the way I want (like an RPC call).

Java:   1.5

I am trying to set up a client/server RMI call - the client should call the "square()" method on the server, the server squares the number that's passed, and returns it.

During the process of building this, I put a log4j statement on the server method.

When I try to run the client from the command line, I look up the name in the RMI registry, execute the square() method on the local instance, and get a "NoClassDefFoundError" for log4j on the client as it attempts to run the square() method.

What this is telling me is that the client is attempting to download not only the interface, but the implementation of the server logic as well.  Which, for the situation I'm in, is not what I want.

I've looked and looked, and I can't find an obvious answer for how I should get the system to run the methods remotely, like an RPC call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem - my server implementation was not extending UnicastRemoteObject.  Apparently this causes the RMI server logic to send the client a copy of the server implementation code, instead of a stub representation of the server implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

or it could be telling you that it's marshalling the exception back to the client for you to see if (trying to pretend that the network boundary isn't there)

if you remove the log4j call from the `square()`;, does it work?

also if you make the server call it's `square()` method locally (e.g when your server proces starts up) does this work? - this will tell you if you are missing a jar dependency somewhere in the log4j call stack.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're having `NoClassDefFoundError` Error is because the JVM/ClassLoader is trying to create a new instance of a class but the definition of the class is not found.

Make sure that the `log4j.jar` or `log4j-x.x.xx.jar` (where `x.x.xx` is the log4j version) exists in your RMI server **and** client. Compile your project and build it to include the log4j.jar inside it.